# SQL, Group by, merge strings

Tags: sql, group-by

I have this table:

```
name    count1    count2   address
John      5         0      London
John      0         3      London
Phil      1         0      Paris
```

I want to get

```
name    count1    count2   address
John      5         3      London
Phil      1         0      Paris
```

So I want to sum count1 and sum count2 and group by name but merge address (since address is always going to be the same for each name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is SQL aggregates 101 (which I'm still learning, btw):

```
select name, sum(count1), sum(count2), address
from mytable
group by name, address;
```

Comment: How about `address`, not in group by nor aggregate?

Comment: @Magnus Look at the question, this is what OP requested.

Comment: Does not work with sql-server. Address needs to be aggregated.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Well, it does with mysql.

Comment: @OlafDietsche: This is because MySQL does not comply with the SQL standard in its default configuration. This will *not* work with any standards-compliant SQL environment, nor will it work if you turn on the standards-compliance feature in MySQL.

Comment: @AdamRobinson Thanks, I didn't know that. I just looked it up and it is indeed documented in the mysql manual under [Server SQL Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by).

Comment: Of course, so obvious... Worked in sqlite, thank you very much!

Comment: @user1741398: It shouldn't be obvious, though, as it goes entirely against the idea of grouping; non-grouped columns *must* be aggregated. Including a non-grouped column outside of an aggregate has no defined behavior, and is a feature that exists only to support poorly-written SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by name and address:

```
SELECT name, address, sum(count1), sum(count2)
FROM table
GROUP BY name, address
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to group by name **and** address:

```
select name, sum(count1)as count1, sum(count2)as count2, address
from dbo.table
group by name, address;
```

Basically a `GROUP BY` *merges* records.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query. How you include address really depends on the the database you are using.

```
select name, sum(count1) count1,sum(count2) count2 ,address
from table1
group by name, address
```

[SQLFiddle to play with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f432c/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t like the double group by solution, you can use select inside from as well:

```
select distinct temp.name, temp.count1, temp.count2, t.address
from mytable t, (select t2.name, sum(t2.count1) as count1, sum(t2.count2) as count2
                 from mytable t2
                 group by t2.name) as temp
where t.name = temp.name
```